# Using quill-image-resize-module in vue2-editor does not implement ImageResize

Tags: vue.js

I am making smart text int Vue.js, and I want to implement resize image option using quill-image-resize-module in vue2-editor,
But at this point:

```
import {VueEditor, Quill} from "vue2-editor";
import ImageResize from "quill-image-resize-module";
Quill.register("modules/imageResize", ImageResize);
```

I am getting this error

[image]

I also intalled it with `npm i --save quill-image-resize-vue` but it still does not work.

What can I do?

Comment: Try `import { ImageResize } from 'quill-image-resize-module'`.

Comment: @User28 it give the same error

Comment: @MichelGisenaël I think the problem might be caused by this [line](https://github.com/kensnyder/quill-image-resize-module/blob/master/src/modules/Toolbar.js#L6). I believe that you can use webpack provide plugin to solve this. I found this [comment](https://github.com/kensnyder/quill-image-resize-module/issues/106#issuecomment-698684352) that might help.

Comment: I used  quill-image-resize-vue instead and it work